# How to restart my game in javascript when a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jscript

I,n totally a beginner in javascript programming. I followed this rock paper scissors game making tutorial through youtube. But I can't make my program to restart and before that say a message showing that "Player wins!"/"Computer wins". Please give your suggestions to improve my code. The full code is provided down below:

```
const game = () => {
  let pScore = 0;
  let cScore = 0;

  //Start the Game
  const startGame = () => {
    const playBtn = document.querySelector(".intro button");
    const introScreen = document.querySelector(".intro");
    const match = document.querySelector(".match");

    playBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      introScreen.classList.add("fadeOut");
      match.classList.add("fadeIn");
    });
  };

  //Play Match
  const playMatch = () => {
    const options = document.querySelectorAll(".options button");
    const playerHand = document.querySelector(".player-hand");
    const computerHand = document.querySelector(".computer-hand");
    const hands = document.querySelectorAll(".hands img");

    hands.forEach((hand) => {
      hand.addEventListener("animationend", function () {
        this.style.animation = "";
      });
    });
    //Computer Options
    const computerOptions = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

    options.forEach((option) => {
      option.addEventListener("click", function () {
        //Computer Choice
        const computerNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        const computerChoice = computerOptions[computerNumber];

        setTimeout(() => {
          //Here is where we call compare hands
          compareHands(this.textContent, computerChoice);
          //Update Images
          playerHand.src = `./assets/${this.textContent}.png`;
          computerHand.src = `./assets/${computerChoice}.png`;
        }, 2000);

        //Animation
        playerHand.style.animation = "shakePlayer 2s ease";
        computerHand.style.animation = "shakeComputer 2s ease";
      });
    });
  };

  const updateScore = () => {
    const playerScore = document.querySelector(".player-score p");
    const computerScore = document.querySelector(".computer-score p");
    playerScore.textContent = pScore;
    computerScore.textContent = cScore;
  };

  const compareHands = (playerChoice, computerChoice) => {
    //Update Text
    const winner = document.querySelector(".winner");
    //Checking for a tie
    if (playerChoice === computerChoice) {
      winner.textContent = "It's a tie!";
      return;
    }
    //Check for Rock
    if (playerChoice === "rock") {
      if (computerChoice === "scissors") {
        winner.textContent = "Player wins!";
        pScore++;
        updateScore();
        return;
      } else {
        winner.textContent = "Computer wins!";
        cScore++;
        updateScore();
        return;
      }
    }
    //Check for Paper
    if (playerChoice === "paper") {
      if (computerChoice === "scissors") {
        winner.textContent = "Computer wins!";
        cScore++;
        updateScore();
        return;
      } else {
        winner.textContent = "Player wins!";
        pScore++;
        updateScore();
        return;
      }
    }
    //Check for scissors
    if (playerChoice === "scissors") {
      if (computerChoice === "rock") {
        winner.textContent = "Computer wins!";
        cScore++;
        updateScore();
        return;
      } else {
        winner.textContent = "Player wins!";
        pScore++;
        updateScore();
        return;
      }
    }
  };
  //Is call all the inner function
  startGame();
  playMatch();
};

//Start the game function
game();
```

Comment: If you want to restart the game, you probably need to reset some of the variables (which reflects the game's state), clear the text in some of the elements, and invoke `game()` again.

Comment: Make it a standard to reset variables in a method, apart from setting listeners and references to HTML elements. Add a check for end condition (best of three), otherwise, repeat  `playMatch()` (without setting the references to the HTML elements). Create the game as a Class. `compareHands` got lots of repeatable code. Ponder how you can reduce that code. Should make it with less than 50% of the number of characters you're using now. Make it a habit to separate UI updates and game logic to create cleaner code, like you have done in `updateScore()`.

Answer (score -1):

you can add click event listener on window and the reload the page.

```
window.addEventListener('click',()=>{ location.reload()})
```